# How to write a traffic light "get program" and "get phase" functions in traci interface?

Tags: veins

Checking in the TraCICommandInterface there are only two function for the traffic lights. The first one is `setProgram` and the other one is `setPhaseIndex` how can I write the get functions for them?

Comment: StackOverflow is all about collecting good answers to (good) questions. If you were able to find a good answer yourself, feel free to add it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **TraCICommandInterface.h:** insert the following functions definitions under traffic light methods:

```
// Trafficlight methods
std::string getProgram();
int getPhaseIndex();
```

In **TraCICommandInterface.cc:** insert the following functions declarations:

```
std::string TraCICommandInterface::Trafficlight::getProgram() {
    return traci->genericGetString(CMD_GET_TL_VARIABLE, trafficLightId, TL_CURRENT_PROGRAM,RESPONSE_GET_TL_VARIABLE);
}
```

and

```
int TraCICommandInterface::Trafficlight::getPhaseIndex() {
    return traci->genericGetInt(CMD_GET_TL_VARIABLE, trafficLightId, TL_CURRENT_PHASE,RESPONSE_GET_TL_VARIABLE);
}
```